# Getting "Can't run the JVM" when starting Ardor on Windows 10

Tags: windows, ardor

When running Ardor 2.2.1 on Windows 10, I'm getting "Can't run the JVM" error. Also tried going to the command line and going to:

C:\Program Files\Ardor

and running run.bat

It just pops open a window and closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit the run.bat file you'll notice the last line that begins with **start**

I copied that line and made the java.exe paths absolute instead of relative and pasted this line into the command line window:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe" -cp classes;lib*;conf;addons\classes;addons\lib* -Dnxt.runtime.mode=desktop nxt.Nxt

If Ardor starts, that just means your java paths are not working properly in windows.

Comment: Solution is to uninstall java and reinstall Ardor without java.